# Convert Bootstrap 3 Fancy Tab Element to Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap 3 tab component copied from bootsnip, I was able to upgrade it from Bootstrap 3.2.0 to 3.3.7 without hassle. Now I want to integrate it into my project using Bootstrap 4.1.0 but I can't get the Tabs to center and get most of the same behavior.

Bootstrap 3 HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                <p>This is my attempt to make a wonderful snippet posted by
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com/maridlcrmn">maridlcrmn</a> a little more responsive. You can find the orginal
                    <a target="_parent" href="http://bootsnipp.com/maridlcrmn/snippets/QbEpr">here</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active">
                            <a href="#dustin" aria-controls="dustin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dustinlamont/128.jpg" />
                                <span class="quote">
                                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="">
                            <a href="#daksh" aria-controls="daksh" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dakshbhagya/128.jpg" />
                                <span class="quote">
                                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="">
                            <a href="#anna" aria-controls="anna" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/annapickard/128.jpg" />
                                <span class="quote">
                                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="">
                            <a href="#wafer" aria-controls="wafer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                <img class="img-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/waferbaby/128.jpg" />
                                <span class="quote">
                                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content" id="tabs-collapse">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dustin">
                            <div class="tab-inner">
                                <p class="lead">Etiam tincidunt enim et pretium efficitur. Donec auctor leo sollicitudin eros iaculis sollicitudin.</p>
                                <hr>
                                <p>
                                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Dustin Lamont</strong>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <em class="text-capitalize"> Senior web developer</em> at
                                    <a href="#">Apple</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="daksh">
                            <div class="tab-inner">
                                <p class="lead">Suspendisse dictum gravida est, nec consequat tortor venenatis a. Suspendisse vitae venenatis
                                    sapien.
                                </p>
                                <hr>
                                <p>
                                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Daksh Bhagya</strong>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <em class="text-capitalize"> UX designer</em> at
                                    <a href="#">Google</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="anna">
                            <div class="tab-inner">
                                <p class="lead">Nullam suscipit ante ac arcu placerat, nec sagittis quam volutpat. Vestibulum aliquam facilisis
                                    velit ut ultrices.</p>
                                <hr>
                                <p>
                                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Anna Pickard</strong>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <em class="text-capitalize"> Master web developer</em> at
                                    <a href="#">Intel</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="wafer">
                            <div class="tab-inner">
                                <p class="lead"> Fusce erat libero, fermentum quis sollicitudin id, venenatis nec felis. Morbi sollicitudin gravida
                                    finibus.
                                </p>
                                <hr>
                                <p>
                                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Wafer Baby</strong>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <em class="text-capitalize"> Web designer</em> at
                                    <a href="#">Microsoft</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a {
    position: relative;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a:hover,
.nav.nav-justified>li>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a>.quote {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #13c0ba;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li.active>a>.quote {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #13c0ba;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    transform: scale(.8, .8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.nav.nav-justified>li.active>a>img,
.nav.nav-justified>li:hover>a>img,
.nav.nav-justified>li:focus>a>img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.tab-pane .tab-inner {
    padding: 30px 0 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav.nav-justified>li>a>.quote {
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

How can I get the same behavior as above in bootstrap 4? Here's my code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <p>This is my attempt to make a wonderful snippet posted by
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com/maridlcrmn">maridlcrmn</a> a little more responsive. You can find the orginal
          <a target="_parent" href="http://bootsnipp.com/maridlcrmn/snippets/QbEpr">here</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" role="tabpanel">
        
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-justified justify-content-center" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#dustin" aria-controls="dustin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dustinlamont/128.jpg" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#daksh" aria-controls="daksh" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dakshbhagya/128.jpg" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#anna" aria-controls="anna" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/annapickard/128.jpg" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#wafer" aria-controls="wafer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/waferbaby/128.jpg" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="col">
          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content" id="tabs-collapse">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dustin">
              <div class="tab-inner">
                <p class="lead">Etiam tincidunt enim et pretium efficitur. Donec auctor leo sollicitudin eros iaculis sollicitudin.</p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                  <strong class="text-uppercase">Dustin Lamont</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <em class="text-capitalize"> Senior web developer</em> at
                  <a href="#">Apple</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="daksh">
              <div class="tab-inner">
                <p class="lead">Suspendisse dictum gravida est, nec consequat tortor venenatis a. Suspendisse vitae venenatis sapien.
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                  <strong class="text-uppercase">Daksh Bhagya</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <em class="text-capitalize"> UX designer</em> at
                  <a href="#">Google</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="anna">
              <div class="tab-inner">
                <p class="lead">Nullam suscipit ante ac arcu placerat, nec sagittis quam volutpat. Vestibulum aliquam facilisis velit ut
                  ultrices.</p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                  <strong class="text-uppercase">Anna Pickard</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <em class="text-capitalize"> Master web developer</em> at
                  <a href="#">Intel</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="wafer">
              <div class="tab-inner">
                <p class="lead"> Fusce erat libero, fermentum quis sollicitudin id, venenatis nec felis. Morbi sollicitudin gravida finibus.
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                  <strong class="text-uppercase">Wafer Baby</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <em class="text-capitalize"> Web designer</em> at
                  <a href="#">Microsoft</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS for Bootstrap 4 example:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a {
    position: relative;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a:hover,
.nav.nav-justified>li>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #13c0ba;
}

.nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    transform: scale(.8, .8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.nav.nav-justified>li.active>a>img,
.nav.nav-justified>li:hover>a>img,
.nav.nav-justified>li:focus>a>img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.tab-pane .tab-inner {
    padding: 30px 0 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter, Use justify-content-center on ul

Also remove left:0; style from .nav.nav-justified>li>a>.quote

Change the following style

```
.nav.nav-justified>li>a>.quote {
    top: 40px;
    right: -1px;
}
```

Update your css with this one

```
body {
      padding-top: 60px;
  }

  .nav.nav-justified>li>a {
      position: relative;
  }

  .nav.nav-justified>li>a:hover,
  .nav.nav-justified>li>a:focus {
      background-color: transparent;
  }

  .nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #13c0ba;
  }
  .nav.nav-justified>li.active>a>img,
  .nav.nav-justified>li:hover>a>img,
  .nav.nav-justified>li:focus>a>img {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: none;
      transform: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
      transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }
  .nav.nav-justified>li>a>img {
      max-width: 80%;
      opacity: .3;
      -webkit-transform: scale(.8, .8);
      transform: scale(.8, .8);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
      transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }



  .tab-pane .tab-inner {
      padding: 30px 0 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Nandita, thanks for your comment, I just replaced `text-center` with `justify-content-center` but it still didn't work. It even removed the center class on the remaining texts.

Comment: Sorry use the justify-content-center class on <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">

Comment: Wow, It worked! Thank you very much. Centering the tabs worked after applying, justify-content-center class on <ul class="nav nav-justified" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">. The quotes won't be needed anyway, so I'm removing it.
However, one more thing let's assume the quote is now removed. The tabs still don't behave as expected any suggestions on how to fix that? Looks like the first element in the tab remains active forever. Upon page refresh nothing is showing beneath.

Comment: I have updated the bootstrap 4 section of the code with the latest working version after applying the class to ul as instructed above and also removed the quotes. The last part is getting the tabs to behave exactly how it is in the bootstrap 3 example. I'll appreciate if you can take a look again. Thanks

Comment: Remove class active from <li role="presentation" class="active">
Also can you please post the updated css.

Comment: removed the active class and removed everything that has to do with quote from the css, I have updated the question with a new section, CSS for Bootstrap 4 example. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much Nandita, finally got what I wanted by recreating from scratch. Turns out all I really needed was the class justify-content-center, that really got me started. Now here's what I got - https://imgur.com/EYGE1Gd
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I always meant to say the same thing to you. Whenever you upgrade css version(eg: bootstrap in your case), try to recreate it from scratch.(atleast the custom css that you applied) The more you try to work-up on the existing code, the more confused you will get. It will probably become what you desire, but your code will no longer be clean. So try recreating from scratch. It may take few extra minutes but will save you a lot of time later when you look at a clean code .

Comment: You are right, starting from scratch really did save me a lot of time, I was able to fix errors pretty quickly and make changes as much and as fast as I want without too much worry about what class to apply it to. Anyway thanks again.